# Highcharts Navigator with a table?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is it possible to use a Highcharts navigator with a given data set and time range to trigger an event to filter the data set displayed in a regular HTML table below? I dont want the main chart at all, just want to use the navigator functionality.

Basically, I'm visualizing a time picker, say for the past 7 days, with a data plot for the last 7 days - with the last "24" hours selected, and a HTML table below this highcharts navigator.

As the user changes his time range selection in the navigator, my event listener would trigger a change in the rows displayed below in the HTML table.

Anyone have suggestions on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set small height for a chart and add sepcific series for navigator. Something like that: http://jsfiddle.net/Yrygy/137/

```
var chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        height: 120
    },
    yAxis: {
        height: 1   
    },
    xAxis: {
        min: 2,
        max: 4,
        lineWidth: 0,
        tickLength: 0,
        labels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    },
    navigator: {
        series: {
            data: [1,2,3,4,2,3,4,2,33,4,4,3,2,3,2,3,3,2,2,3,4]    
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [null]   
    }]
});
```